# Converting excel to csv with date column does not work as expected

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to convert an excel file to csv. 
In this file i have a column with dates, sometimes they are filled in, but sometimes we do not have a date yet. 
But i cannot get it to work as expected.
Besides the python file we also have a json file with lots of config in because we have to swap out a lot of values during the conversion with new values.

Attempt 1

```
    def format_dates():
        for datecolumn in config["dateformats"]:
            if datecolumn["column"] in columns:
                outputdata[datecolumn["column"]] = outputdata[datecolumn["column"]].dt.strftime(datecolumn["format"])
```

This converted the dates but if a date in a row was empty the script failed.

For our next attempt we did it like this.

```
    for datecolumn in config["dateformats"]:
        if datecolumn["column"] in columns:
            outputdata[datecolumn["column"]] = pd.to_datetime(outputdata[datecolumn["column"]], format = datecolumn["format"], errors='coerce')
```

This did not yield any errors but after a check in the converted file it seems that there where no dates migrated at all, so this was a bust.

In the json file we have following config for the date format.

```
"dateformats": [
        {
            "column": "date column",
            "datatype": "date",
            "format": "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"
        }
```

So what i need is that this column is migrated to the csv file, with the correct date format, if the column is not filled in it should be empty in the new file.

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Since attempt 1 works unless the date column is empty, you just have to modify that a bit.

If the empty date column causes an exception you could catch that and just substitute an empty value for the date field in that row of the CSV file.

Or you could test that the value of the date column is not the empty string and then convert.

Since your question does not contain the actual trace of the failure, I cannot be more specific.

Comment: Thanks, don't know why i did not come up with the idea myself.